# Why is this Javascript throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, html, microdata

I'm working in the latest version of Opera. It supports the Microdata API, but when I typed the following code, it does not work.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var user = document.getItems('http://schema.org/Person')[0];
        alert('Hi there ' + user.properties['name'][0].textContent + '!');
        function supports_microdata_api() {
             return !!document.getItems;
        }
        alert(supports_microdata_api());
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">Fatima Zohra</span>
  <img src="" itemprop="image" />
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could edit your question to add the _actual_ error message rather than "Is not working".

Comment: Using the Opera Developer Tools console, it throws *Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'user' to object. Error thrown at line 30, column 8*.

Comment: Simple JS error, not related to Microdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the page loads; you're calling for something:

```
document.getItems('http://schema.org/Person')[0]
```

That's not part of the DOM yet; your code is run before the DOM is aware of the "yet unseen" element.

Use `window.onload` to wait for the page `onload` event to fire, which occurs after the elements have been parsed.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var user = document.getItems('http://schema.org/Person')[0];
    console.log(user);
    console.log('user.properties Name: ' + user.properties['name'][0].textContent);
    function supports_microdata_api() {
        return !!document.getItems;
    }
    console.log(supports_microdata_api());
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eY63s/2/

Or, alternately, put the code *after* the DOM elements in page order.

A more modern method is to use event delegation:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var user = document.getItems('http://schema.org/Person')[0];
    console.log(user);
    console.log('user.properties Name: ' + user.properties['name'][0].textContent);
    function supports_microdata_api() {
        return !!document.getItems;
    }
    console.log(supports_microdata_api());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eY63s/3/

Although at least earlier versions of IE support `element.attachEvent` instead, [IE9 or later](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener#Compatibility) browsers do/will support `element.addEventListener`.

And this is a safer way to check and call the methods:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var user;

    function supports_microdata_api() {
        return !!document.getItems;
    }

    console.log('Microdata support: ' + supports_microdata_api());

    if (supports_microdata_api()) {
        user = document.getItems('http://schema.org/Person')[0];
        console.log(user);
        console.log('user.properties Name: ' + user.properties['name'][0].textContent);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eY63s/4/

Note the use of `var user` inside the anonymous function, which creates a closure and prevents `user` from escaping to the global scope. This is a "better" way of handling variables, which can help prevent them from being overwritten by accident due to global sharing. On the other hand, you will not be able to call `user` from outside that scope. Resist the urge to push it to the global scope, though, which can be easier but is a bad habit and prone to at times difficult to find errors.